# How to only remove top widget from stack, if user tap on that in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to detect user tapped on top of widget in stack to remove it from onTap function?

I have list of widgets and tree structure is `positioned(gave random values to top, right, bottom)->Transfor.rotate->Align->container`. this list is in `GestureDetector->Stack`

```
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            stackList.removeLast();
          });
        }
```

I can able remove top of widget from stack but how can I find user only tapped on top widget in stack?

In initState, generating 20 of Positioned widgets and storing in list and passing that list into stack as child to gestureDetector as below

Below is Scaffold home statefulclass:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('tapped!');
        setState(() { //Here somehow need to find user tapped on top widget on stack or not
          stackList.removeLast();
        });
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...stackList,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make a few modifications to how your widget is composed. I managed to get it working using the following Tree Structure

```
Positioned -> Transform.rotate -> Align -> GestureDetector -> Container
```

I created a Widget which will hold this Widget tree

```dart
class TappablePositionedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Container child;
  final double bottom;
  final double right;
  final double top;
  final double angle;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final AlignmentGeometry alignment;

  TappablePositionedWidget({
    this.angle,
    this.onTap,
    this.bottom,
    this.child,
    this.right,
    this.top,
    this.alignment,
  }) {
    assert(alignment != null);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: top,
      right: right,
      bottom: bottom,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: angle,
        child: Align(
          alignment: alignment,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: onTap,
            child: child,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then populate the stack list with instances of this widget.

```dart
List<TappablePositionedWidget> stackList = [
    TappablePositionedWidget(
      bottom: Random().nextInt(200).toDouble(),
      top: Random().nextInt(200).toDouble(),
      right: Random().nextInt(200).toDouble(),
      angle: Random().nextInt(360).toDouble(),
      alignment: randomAlignment,
      child: Container(
        height: 240,
        width: 250,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Code to generate random alignment

```dart
static AlignmentGeometry get randomAlignment {
  int index = Random().nextInt(9);
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return Alignment.centerLeft;
      break;
    case 1:
      return Alignment.centerRight;
      break;
    case 2:
      return Alignment.center;
      break;
    case 3:
      return Alignment.bottomCenter;
      break;
    case 4:
      return Alignment.topCenter;
      break;
    case 5:
      return Alignment.bottomLeft;
      break;
    case 6:
      return Alignment.bottomRight;
      break;
    case 7:
      return Alignment.topLeft;
      break;
    case 8:
      return Alignment.topRight;
      break;
    default:
      return Alignment.center;
      break;
  }
}
```

Finally populate the stack

```dart
Stack(
  children: stackList.map((widget) {
    if (stackList.indexOf(widget) == stackList.length - 1) {
      return TappablePositionedWidget(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            stackList.removeLast();
          });
        },
        right: widget.right,
        angle: widget.angle,
        top: widget.top,
        bottom: widget.bottom,
        child: widget.child,
        alignment: widget.alignment,
      );
    }
    return widget;
  }).toList(),
)
```

**EDIT**

To initialize the `stackList` add this code

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    stackList.add(TappablePositionedWidget(
      bottom: Random().nextInt(200).toDouble(),
      top: Random().nextInt(200).toDouble(),
      right: Random().nextInt(200).toDouble(),
      angle: Random().nextInt(360).toDouble(),
      alignment: randomAlignment,
      child: Container(
        height: 240,
        width: 250,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked, perfectly.
How can we generate stackList with 10 TappablePositionedWidgets in initState?

Comment: so here
```
if (stackList.indexOf(widget) == stackList.length - 1) {
      return TappablePositionedWidget(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            stackList.removeLast();
          });
        },
```

if we tapped on top widget then it gives TappablePositionedWidget but if user tapped on any other widget, how do we know which one tapped?

based on that I want to show some Text widget. @Ajil O.

Comment: you could handle that in an `else` clause right? I didn't really get your point

Comment: I am trying to show some text on top of stack like GAME OVER if user tapped on any container(here square) other than top one in stack

Tried else n else if but not working!

Comment: this helped me, in else added this.
```
onTap: () {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Tap"));

        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      },
 ```

Thanks you once again.

Comment: After onTap on top widget, next subsequent widget moving its position!! Any idea?

Comment: Without seeing how you are doing this, I can not help. Maybe post a different question if you can't figure it out by yourself